# Onclick event for all search text boxes

Tags: jquery

I want to add an onclick event to all the input textboxes on my page having the following attributes:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="" class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="1">
```

Can anyone please let me know the jquery command for the same.

Comment: Keep calm and Google.

Answer (score 1):

Use `attribute selector` to select all those text boxes then attach the click event for the same.

Try,

```
$('input[type="search"]').click(function(){

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$("input[type='search'].tablesorter-filter").click(function(){
 alert();
 //your own logic here
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dKd8y/)